# Сабмит формы без потери данных в инпуте

Tags: php

Дорогие друзья, вопрос будет звучать довольно странно , но всё же это нужно...
Есть файл outgoing_personal_add.php, в нем есть форма такого содержания

```
<form action="outgoing_personal_add_save.php" method="POST">
<tr>         
<td><?php echo $row5020['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo "<input type='number' class='form-control' name = 'qty' d='qty'/>"; ?></td>
<td><?php echo "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-info btn-block'>Добавить</button>" ?></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

После сабмита файл-обработчик берет данные делает своё дело и обратно редиректит на страницу с формой (т е  в файл outgoing_personal_add.php) и после редиректа веденные данные пользователем в инпут исчезают (само собой). Как сделать чтоб данные в инпуте не исчезали а оставались до полного закрытия страницы например.

PS редирект происходит с помощью

```
header('Location: '.$url);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.е. вопрос в том, чтобы заполнить на форме одно число? Ну сделайте так

outgoing_personal_add_save.php

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['qty'])) {
  $_SESSION['qty'] = $_POST['qty'];
  ..........
} else
  unset($_SESSION['qty']);
```

outgoing_personal_add.php

```
session_start();
..........
<td>
  <?php
    printf(
      "<input type='number' class='form-control' name = 'qty' d='qty' value='%s'/>",
       $_SESSION['qty'] ?? ''
    );
  ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Спасибо , Anton Shchyrov, дело в том что у меня в сессииях хранится другая информация, но следуя Вашему ответу в голову пришло другая идея как раз так и решающая мою проблему. Так же спасибо Dan the Hat за ответ

Comment: @AlexStassov Как одна информация в сессии может помешать другой?

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1.

Не использовать редирект. В пхп части прописать `if(!empty($_POST['ваши пост данные тут']))`. При наличии `$_POST` данных делать с ними то что хотите, и так же отдавать их в дефолтное значение поля.

Вариант 2.

Если данные куда-либо пишутся - брать их от туда, куда они пишутся.

P.S. Если Вы предоставите более полную картину - Вам дадут более полный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
<td>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <?php echo $row5020['name']; ?>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="qty" value="<?=(isset($_POST['qwe']))?$_POST['qty']:'';?>" />
        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-info btn-block'>Добавить</button>
    </form>
</td>
...
```